# How to get HtmlElement from Angular component outside component?

Tags: angular

I've searched too much, but all of them get `HTMLElement` inside the component itself or in other components.
I want to get `HTMLElement` by an Angular Component inside a helper or something like that:

```
function getHtmlElement(component: any) : HTMLElement{
// Do something
}
```

Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: Is your component rendered by the router or rendered just statically? Usually the information flow is from services to a component (e.g. via observables). If you explain your use case I can try to provide something which is more of a best practice.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus I'm using some libraries and they want me to provide `HTMLElement` to render the other output. But I don't want to create `HTMLElement` and `append` div by div like that. So I want to create a new Angular Component and in some way, I can convert it to `HTMLElement`.  Hope you got my point

Comment: Why don't you instantiate the library code in the related component? This would encapsulate the logic of actually integration the library to this component as a single point of entry. You can get the HTMLElement of this component in the constructor passing `ElementRef`. To invoke this logic from other components you can use a service to publish and subscribe all data needed.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus I got your point, but I can't. If really no way to do that. I think a have to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation to give a little bit more context: The problem here is that it's not easy to be determined, since the component can be contained in the DOM multiple times (or even 0 zero times). It can be rendered already, it can change and popup somewhere else. These are all questions that makes it difficult for the single function to find the correct element. If it's not clear to me, since it's so dynamic, how would you be able to write a function who get's exactly the correct element?

Nevertheless what you could do is just inject the whole document in the constructor of your service (or whereever `getHtmlElement()` is contained) and then use native browser APIs to query for the element:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
//prints out the first element found
    console.log(this.document.getElementsByTagName('your-component')[0])
  }
```